# Rename file in a directory using shell

Tags: shell, rename

Suppose I have some files in a dir called `test_dir`, like `a.sh`, `b.sh`, `c.sh`, `d.bash`, and so on. I need to change all the file `*.sh` to `*.bash`. How can I achieve it using shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be done in a single one-liner:

```
ls *.sh | while read i; do mv "$i" "${i%.sh}.bash"; done
```